# The ring of Resurgence

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Because I sold my one of my dragon masks, I have to go back from an old save (I'm PS3) to get them, so it kinda feels like I'm starting over.  It's level 37, so it's not too bad.  I have most of the stuff I really want, however I don't have the ring of resurgence, which regenerates magicka 80%.  Anyone know where it is so I can keep my eye out for it when I get to it?

Comment: In addition to the answers, you could always enchant a ring yourself if your enchanting is good enough. Not sure how high you can self-enchant magicka regen though.

Comment: @Katustrawfic, what do you me by 'self enchant'? The magicka regen can be found, but my enchantment level is crap.  I would never make it up to 80%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ring of Resurgence is not a unique item, it can be randomly found in loot and in shops. Look for it in chests (particularly boss chests) and merchants that sell enchanted jewelry.

Comment: That's what I thought :( I kinda didn't want to have to go looting every single burial urn again but, I guess I'll have to look out for it... Meanwhile, I've got daggers to forge :(

Answer (score 4):

It's a generic magic item and thus is found as random loot (specifically starting at level 32). There are no set locations for them.